# Crystal Reports - Create Multiple PDFs from One Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to print a report in Crystal Reports to multiple PDFs, for example if you had an invoice report that needed to be exported to individual PDF documents?

I know this can be done manually, but I would like to set it up to automatically create these PDFs based on the criteria I set up.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/f85e167d-edb3-44d0-82fc-2d2b6f92f57b), it's not possible.

But, you could write a little application that would enumerate pages and call [ReportDocument.PrintReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28VS.71%29.aspx) to each page, then configure your PDF printer to save them automatically with some generated file names.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 companies have products to do that, and the technique is called "bursting":

http://www.reportrunner.com

http://www.christainsteven.com

Comment: This software also does it:
https://apbreports.com/cr-dispatch.html

Disclosure: I am the owner of APB Reports.